# Remove 'Edit this page to modify your web part content' from CEWP

Tags: sharepoint-2010, cewp

I added Content Editor Webpart in my Sharepoint page. If there is no content provided in CEWP then 'Edit this page to modify your web part content' default text is displaying in the page. How do i remove this default text.

Note: I added this CEWP in page layout, using this page layout I have created several pages. So now I have to modify in page layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added   (space) in below section of Content Editor Webpart. thats it. it worked for me

```
<Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></Content>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Jquery I give one solution for you,

Load `Jquery latest URL to Your site` and Use Following Code from Remove 'Edit this page to modify your web part content' default text is displaying in the page in CEWP.

```
$("[id^='WebPartWPQ']").empty();
```

Hope this is helpful for you.